# Trying to use tensorflow.io.gfile.GFile and tensorflow.dataset.map, getting "Expected binary or unicode string, got Tensor dtype=string

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm quite new to using Tensorflow, and imagine someone will quickly tell me I'm doing something stupid so here goes.

I'm working with the MSTAR dataset and trying to get it read in. The files have a very strange format, but suffice it to say that if eager execution is on the following code reads and displays an image from the dataset.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tf.enable_eager_execution()

img1Path='HB15000.018'
img2Path='HB15001.018'

def pathToImgTF(path):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(path,'rb') as filePath:
        step1=filePath.readlines()
        step2=[x.strip(b'\n') for x in step1]
        for x in step2:
            if b'PhoenixHeaderLength' in x:
                line=x.strip().split(b'=')
                PhoenixHeaderLength=int(line[1])
            elif b'native_header_length' in x:
                line=x.strip().split(b'=')
                native_header_length=int(line[1])
            elif b'NumberOfColumns' in x:
                line=x.strip().split(b'=')
                NumberOfColumns=int(line[1])
            elif b'NumberOfRows' in x:
                line=x.strip().split(b'=')
                NumberOfRows=int(line[1])
        filePath.seek(PhoenixHeaderLength+native_header_length)
        step3=tf.decode_raw(filePath.read(),out_type=tf.float32,little_endian=False)
        depth_major=tf.reshape(step3,[2,NumberOfRows,NumberOfColumns])
        image=tf.transpose(depth_major,[1,2,0])[:,:,0] #Cut off phase for now
    return image

img=pathToImgTF(imgPath)
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
```

I would like to use tf.dataset.from_tensor_slices, but it appears that isn't an option because the following code:

```
ds=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([img1Path,img2Path])
ds=ds.map(pathToImgTF)
```

Gives the error "TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=() dtype=string"

The traceback looks to me like it's breaking specifically on 'filePath.readlines()', any help would be greatly appreciated.

Full error output:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last) ipython-input-6-e12909fb73cd in module
>         1 ds=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([img1Path,img2Path])
>   ----> 2 ds=ds.map(pathToImgTF)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py
>   in map(self, map_func, num_parallel_calls)    1770     if
>   num_parallel_calls is None:    1771       return DatasetV1Adapter(
>   -> 1772           MapDataset(self, map_func, preserve_cardinality=False))    1773     else:    1774       return
>   DatasetV1Adapter(
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py
>   in **init**(self, input_dataset, map_func, use_inter_op_parallelism,
>   preserve_cardinality, use_legacy_function)    3188
>   self._transformation_name(),    3189         dataset=input_dataset,
>   -> 3190         use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)    3191     variant_tensor = gen_dataset_ops.map_dataset(    3192
>   input_dataset._variant_tensor,  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py
>   in **init**(self, func, transformation_name, dataset, input_classes,
>   input_shapes, input_types, input_structure, add_to_graph,
>   use_legacy_function, defun_kwargs)    2553       resource_tracker =
>   tracking.ResourceTracker()    2554       with
>   tracking.resource_tracker_scope(resource_tracker):
>   -> 2555         self._function = wrapper_fn._get_concrete_function_internal()    2556         if
>   add_to_graph:    2557
>   self._function.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
>   in _get_concrete_function_internal(self, *args, **kwargs)    1353
>   """Bypasses error checking when getting a graph function."""    1354
>   graph_function =
>   self._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
>   -> 1355         *args, **kwargs)    1356     # We're returning this concrete function to someone, and they may keep a    1357     #
>   reference to the FuncGraph without keeping a reference to the
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
>   in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args,
>   **kwargs)    1347     if self.input_signature:    1348       args, kwargs = None, None
>   -> 1349     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)    1350     return graph_function    1351
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
>   in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)    1650
>   graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
>   1651       if graph_function is None:
>   -> 1652         graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)    1653         self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] =
>   graph_function    1654       return graph_function, args, kwargs
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
>   in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)    1543             arg_names=arg_names,
>   1544             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
>   -> 1545             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),    1546         self._function_attributes)    1547
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py
>   in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
>   func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
>   arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)
>       713                                           converted_func)
>       714 
>   --> 715       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
>       716 
>       717       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py
>   in wrapper_fn(*args)    2547           attributes=defun_kwargs)
>   2548       def wrapper_fn(*args):  # pylint: disable=missing-docstring
>   -> 2549         ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)    2550         ret = self._output_structure._to_tensor_list(ret)    2551         return
>   [ops.convert_to_tensor(t) for t in ret]
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py
>   in _wrapper_helper(*args)    2487         nested_args = (nested_args,)
>   2488 
>   -> 2489       ret = func(*nested_args)    2490       # If `func` returns a list of tensors, `nest.flatten()` and    2491       #
>   `ops.convert_to_tensor()` would conspire to attempt to stack
>
> in pathToImgTF(path)
>         9 def pathToImgTF(path):
>        10     with tf.io.gfile.GFile(path,'rb') as filePath:
>   ---> 11         step1=filePath.readlines()
>        12         step2=[x.strip(b'\n') for x in step1]
>        13         for x in step2:
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py
>   in readlines(self)
>       181   def readlines(self):
>       182     """Returns all lines from the file in a list."""
>   --> 183     self._preread_check()
>       184     lines = []
>       185     while True:
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py
>   in _preread_check(self)
>        82                                            "File isn't open for reading")
>        83       self._read_buf = pywrap_tensorflow.CreateBufferedInputStream(
>   ---> 84           compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
>        85 
>        86   def _prewrite_check(self):
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py
>   in as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
>        63   else:
>        64     raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
>   ---> 65                     (bytes_or_text,))
>        66 
>        67
>
> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got tf.Tensor
>   'args_0:0' shape=() dtype=string

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of data do `imgPath1` and `imgPath2` have. Anyways, they must be  of tensor type with predefined data type. These two consists the actual data.

If that is the case, then change the square brackets to circular brackets as follows-
`ds=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imgPath1,imgPath2))`

If this still throwing the same error, then please give information where exactly it is throwing the error.

Comment: Those two are two separate files in the same dataset which both need processed. I couldn't give the example code with just one file as the program throws "Unbatching a tensor is only supported for rank >= 1". I'm sorry for the confusion, I will edit the post so that they are "img1Path" and "img2Path instead.